# build now option is not coming for job in jenkins

Tags: jenkins

I am new user to jenkins. My jenkins version is 1.594. When we got the confirmation from jenkins team about onboarding the jenkin job, i did not find the build now option for the job.

Comment: Can you be more specific?

Comment: @Blackbam, I was not able to see the `build now` option in Jenkins dashboard. But now it is fine as per the suggestion from @dildeepak

Answer (score 6, accepted):

***Build now*** option does not come in either of the below reasons:

1. Project might be disabled. Please enable it or ask the concerned team to enable it.
2. You do not have enough permission to build the project. Please raise the concerned permission.

Comment: I have the developer permission.

Comment: In that case, please check for the first option.

Comment: Job was disabled by CI team. Now i amable to see the `build now` option.Thanks @dildeepak

Comment: In my case despite having all the rights I wasn't able to see the build option. I, myself disable the project and then enabled it and surprisingly it started showing the build now button. It mainly happens when you make copy jobs in the Jenkins.

Answer (score 42):

I just bumped into the same problem, but none of the mentioned solutions worked. I had created a new job using the *Copy from* functionality. I was then sent to the job configuration page. I left this page without pressing *Save* or *Apply*, and the *Build now* link did not appear. I then went back to the configuration page, pressed *Save*, and the *Build with parameters* link became visible.

Comment: save my day, bro!

Comment: If you use the API to copy a job from a template, it doesn't let you build it until you have manually saved it!

Comment: I was in exactly the same situation. This worked for me. Thank you :) +1

Comment: Thank you! refresh page and re-hit save made the build option appear. Saved lots of time

Comment: Thanks for this, just ran in to this myself. Wish there was some sort of indicator to provide a hint at this action needing to be performed.

Answer (score 6):

Add one more possible answer:

Under some circumstances, you may automatically logout and stay at the same page(no button available), try login again fixed my problem...

Answer (score 0):

You can choose "This build is parameterized" in configure and add a dummy Boolean parameter, check default value.
Then you will get a build button

Answer (score 0):

Another reason why "build now" might not appear is if your Jenkins couldn't find your Jenkinsfile. Scan your project and check the log.

If you find a line that says `'Jenkinsfile' not found`, then that's your problem. Check the git repo and make sure the file is there and make sure there isn't a typo in the name.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I had accidentally hit the red X on Behaviors (under Branch Sources with a multi-branch pipeline).  The default behavior "Discover branches" should be there.  You can put it back by choosing the Add option below.